# Mutual Authentication - null cert chain

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, keytool, mutual-authentication

I'm trying to set up mutual (2 way) SSL authentication. Ultimately I will have a mulesoft application (as client) calling a webapp (as the server). For now I am testing using Firefox browser as the client to simplify testing.

I followed this tutorial 
http://www.baeldung.com/x-509-authentication-in-spring-security

and managed to get this working fine. This uses a self signed certificate for the server and a self signed certificate for the client which is installed into firefox to make the client call.

So far so good...

However I am having issues once I try and use certificates signed by my company.

So I have a client certificate which my company has signed. This has been provided as a client.cer file. I can view the details of this and see that it is issued by the company intermediary (which in turn is issued by the company root CA)

The client CSR was created with

```
keytool -genkey -alias client -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore client.jks -dname "CN=client-dev,OU=Dept, O=Company, L=London, ST=Greater London, C=GB"

keytool -certreq -alias client -file client.csr -keystore client.jks
```

The next step of my testing is to try and use this company signed client.cer file to call my server on localhost (which is using a self signed certificate as per the tutorial).

On having received the signed client.cer file the steps I have taken are...

- Import the companies Root.cer into the keystore I used to generate my
  client certificate signing request.
- Import the companies Intermediate.cer into the same keystore.
- Import the client.cer into the same keystore
- I then export a p12 file from this keystore and install this into firefox as my client certificate.

The commands I use to do this are as follows

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias primaryintermediate -file Root.cer -keystore client.jks -storepass <pwd>

keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias secondaryintermediate -file Int.cer -keystore client.jks -storepass <pwd>

keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias client -file client.cer -keystore client.jks -storepass <pwd>

keytool -importkeystore -srcalias client -srckeystore client.jks -srcstorepass <pwd> -destkeystore "client.p12" -deststorepass <pwd> -deststoretype PKCS12
```

However when I try and hit my localhost app endpoint from firefox and view the log output I see the server side SSL handshake succeed but then get a "null cert chain" error in the client handshake. So the following steps look to succeed

- ClientHello
- ServerHello
- Certificate
- CertificateRequest
- ServerHelloDone
- Certificate - Error occurs here

The relevant part of the log looks like this...

```
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Supported Signature Algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, MD5withRSA
Cert Authorities:
<CN=Root>
<CN=client-dev, OU=Dept, O=Company, L=London, ST=Greater London, C=GB>
<CN=Intermediate, DC=HBEU, DC=ADROOT, DC=Company>
*** ServerHelloDone
https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 2710
https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-2, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 77
*** Certificate chain
<Empty>
***
https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-2, fatal error: 42: null cert chain
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain
```

I'm unclear what I have done wrong but assume I must have created the p12 file incorrectly?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?